# Which is correct : 'unless the storm moves off' or 'unless the storm moved off'?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

Time clauses for the future tense do not take future forms – in other words, these time clauses should not include will.

For Example:

> I will start when I am ready. (NOT I will start when I will be ready.)
>   Wait by the bus stop until I come back. (NOT Wait by the bus stop until I will come back.)

OK, that's easy. But I'm confused with this sentence:

> The pilot announced that the plane would not be taking off unless the storm (moves / moved) off.

What is correct? Or both are possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [reported speech](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm). What the pilot actrually said was

> the plane will not be taking off unless the storm moves off.

In reported speech, which happens with verbs like say, ask, announce and quite a few others, we backshift the tense of the verbs in the reported speech. **will** becomes **would**, and **moves** (present simple) becomes **moved** (simple past).

> The pilot announced that the plane **would** not be taking off unless the storm **moved** off.